# SharePoint sp.js not running on Silverlight page

Tags: 2013, silverlight

I am using `sp.js` to display logged in user name on top of my publishing site page. The code is working fine on all pages except on one page where I am displaying ORG BROWSER web part which is Silverlight based. After debugging I came to know that following is the line which is not running and it is not showing any error either. It just doesn't run.

```
alert(userObject.get_title());
```

Even putting it in TRY/CATCH doesn't show any error. What could be the reason for this?